# Returning IEnumerable<string> from Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'm trying to return an `IEnumerable<string>` from a linq query and I'm getting the error:
Cannot convert `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` to `IEnumerable<string>`

I have no idea how to go about fixing this issue.

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllMembers(Type type)
        {    

            var query =
                (from member in type.GetMembers()
                 select new
                 {
                     Member = member.GetType() + " " + member.ToString()

                 }
                );

            return query;
        }
```

Comment: using ToList() will solve your problem

Comment: @Nick - no, it wont.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllMembers(Type type)
    {    

        var query =
            from member in type.GetMembers()
             select member.GetType() + " " + member.ToString();

        return query;
    }
```

You were creating an IEnumerable of anonymous types, when I think you just wanted an enumeration of strings.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating anonymous type with `Member` property. Simply return string values thus you are expect `IEnumerable<string>`

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllMembers(Type type)
{    
    return from member in type.GetMembers()
           select member.GetType() + " " + member.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an anonymous type (constructed by `new {}`) from your query and not a string.
You can modify the query like this for example, so the result is an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
return from member in type.GetMembers()
       select member.GetType() + " " + member.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your query returns an anonymous object with one property `Members` which is a string, simply change to just returning the string:

```
 var query =
            (from member in type.GetMembers()
             select member.GetType() + " " + member.ToString()
            );

  return query;
```